# Multi level lightning table with LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, table, component

Is it possible to create the same table as below (screen was taken from vf page) with lightning-tree-grid in Lightning Web Component?

I tried to do that, but it seems there is no possibility to add columns row for child records with LWC..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried for a while to do something similar, but like you, I found it didn't work great when the data types were different (seems more designed for hierarchies of same data type)

So for now, I am just using Lightning Layout/LayoutItems with for:each loops e.g.

```
<template if:true={otdata} for:each={otdata} for:item='item'>
<lightning-layout key={item.AccountId} multiple-rows="true">
    <lightning-layout-item key={item.AccountId} padding="horizontal-medium" size="1">
        <lightning-button-icon onclick={handleAccountDelete} icon-name="utility:delete" value={item.AccountId} alternative-text="Delete"   class="slds-m-left_xx-small"></lightning-button-icon>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item key={item.AccountId} padding="horizontal-medium" size="3">
        <div class="slds-text-title"> {item.AccountName} </div>
    </lightning-layout-item>

    <lightning-layout-item key={item.AccountId} padding="horizontal-medium" size="8">
        <template if:true={item.Contacts}>
            <lightning-layout size="12" multiple-rows="true">
            <template for:each={item.Contacts} for:item='itemc'>
                <lightning-layout-item key={itemc.Id} size="5">
                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular"> {itemc.LastName}</div>
                </lightning-layout-item>
```